# Eclipse error "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

So today I started to build my first android app following this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5Qi0lb_3nE

After doing about half of the video I got an error "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed"

I cant see the problem, so here is the code I have:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Hello!" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="This is my first android application!" />

<Button android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text ="And this is a Clickable button!!!" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The spot In the video I got stuck at was about 9 minutes into it.

Sorry for not being to specific, I've never used Stockover before.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have more than one root elements in the XML document, and there can only be **one**. You need to change the final `/>` to `>` in the first element (FrameLayout):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah that fixed that, But as soon as I fixed that, 3 more errors popped up... 2 of the error were at both "TextView" lines, and the last one was at the "Button" line.              the error was "error:ERROR: no resource found that matches the given name ( at "text" with value "@string/Hello!"        & another one at

Comment: You need to go into the strings.xml file (res > values > strings.xml) and add those values. e.g. `<string name="hello">Hello!</string>`, or alternatively you could hardcode the string by removing the `@string/` part of that line

Comment: EDIT: I just saw your newest comment, ill do that first.                              ugg, lol, bear with me, I am very new to this. :-) I clicked "Add" do I add <string name="hello">Hello!</string> to the title? or where do I put it?

Comment: Down the bottom of that screen you should see two tabs, _Resources_ and _strings.xml_. Click on _strings.xml_ and you can paste that code in there directly. For your other elements (other TextView and Button), you need to do the same thing. Note that the `name="hello"` is the part you reference here `@string/hello` and the text between the tags is the value you want displayed on the screen, e.g. Hello!

Comment: I wish i could, but it says i dont have enough reputation :(

Comment: Also, when i went into the strings.xml i Added "@string" as the name, and "@string/Hello!" as the value. and that didnt help then i added "Hello" and "android:text="@string/Hello!""@string/Hello!" as the value. and that made 2 errors go away?